What's wrong with my proof that $\text{sup}(A)+\text{sup}(B)\le\text{sup}(A+B)$ Spivak Chapter 8, Problem 13
According to Spivak

To prove that $\text{sup}(A)+\text{sup}(B)\le\text{sup}(A+B)$ it suffices to prove that $\text{sup}(A)+\text{sup}(B)\le\text{sup}(A+B)+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0;$ begin by choosing $x$ in $A$ and $y$ in $B$ with $\text{sup}(A)-x<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\text{sup}(B)-y<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

I found it made more sense to consider $x$ and $y$ such that  $\text{sup}(A)-x\le\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\text{sup}(B)-y\le\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
Then $\text{sup}(A)+ \text{sup}(B)-\epsilon \le x+y\le \text{sup}(A+B)$. (Note that $A+B$ is the set of all $x+y$ where $x$ is in A and $y$ in $B$.)
So $$\text{sup}(A)+ \text{sup}(B)\le \text{sup}(A+B)+\epsilon $$ which means $\text{sup}(A)+ \text{sup}(B)\le \text{sup}(A+B)$.
Q.E.D
But according to Spivak

$\text{sup}(A)+ \text{sup}(B)-\epsilon < x+y \le\text{sup}(A+B)$

However, I believe this just implies $$\text{sup}(A)+ \text{sup}(B)< \text{sup}(A+B)+\epsilon$$ Which is not the desired result
I can't help but feel that Spivak made the mistake here. Any help would be appreciated.

Why is that not the desird result? $U<V$ implies $U\leq V.$

@ThomasAndrews in in this exercise we are trying to prove $\text{sup}(A)+\text{sup}(B)=\text{sup}(A+B)$ by proving $\text{sup}(A)+\text{sup}(B)\le\text{sup}(A+B)$ and $\text{sup}(A)+\text{sup}(B)\ge\text{sup}(A+B)$ I have already proven the latter.

So? $\sup A+\sup B<\sup(A+B)+\epsilon$ doesn't contradict that - you still can only conclude, if that is true for all $\epsilon>0,$ that $\sup A+\sup B\leq \sup(A+B).$

@ThomasAndrews Ok, I understand.  But is my original proof correct?


However, I believe this just implies $$\text{sup}(A)+ \text{sup}(B)< \text{sup}(A+B)+\epsilon$$ Which is not the desired result

But no one said you had to stop there. If $a<b+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, then $a\leq b $.
